# Environment variables specific to Blender? Do they exist?

Tags: command-line, startup-file

Are there any global variables in Blender? I was searching for them in Blender docs, but didn't find anything.

For example, I want to override the default /tmp directory with another directory. But I want to do it by overriding the environment variable.

For example Nuke has `NUKE_TEMP_DIR` variable, which I can simply override with a new value, and every time I start Nuke the temp directory will be as in the variable.

Houdini also has this kind of variables, Maya and so on.

What about Blender?

Comment: Go to Preferences > File and change the default paths you want. If you really need to set environment variables run: `blender --help` from command line and see the Environment Variables section.

Answer (score 6):

```
Environment Variables:
  $BLENDER_USER_CONFIG      Directory for user configuration files.
  $BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS     Directory for user scripts.
  $BLENDER_SYSTEM_SCRIPTS   Directory for system wide scripts.
  $BLENDER_USER_DATAFILES   Directory for user data files (icons, translations, ..).
  $BLENDER_SYSTEM_DATAFILES Directory for system wide data files.
  $BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON    Directory for system python libraries.
  $TMP or $TMPDIR           Store temporary files here.
  $SDL_AUDIODRIVER          LibSDL audio driver - alsa, esd, dma.
  $PYTHONHOME               Path to the python directory, eg. /usr/lib/python.
```

But the best way is to modify your prefs (File->path) as said above.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any kind of variable to any type or any object in the manner of python's dictionary.

Try the following:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.scene['MyVar'] = 'this is my custom var'
```

just save the file and reopen that. check the variable:

```
bpy.context.scene['MyVar']
```

you will see the variable is stored!